# CDATA content messed up in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, cdata

I have the following CDATA content in the source string.

```
<![CDATA[This is something inside cdata <b>this is bold</b>]]
```

However, when this gets shown in WYSIWYG editor, this looks like :

```
this is bold]]
```

When i click "source" toolbar and check the contents, ckeditor had modified the original content to :

```
<!--[CDATA[This is something inside cdata <b-->
<p>this is bold]]</p>
```

You can see that ckeditor has tried to comment out CDATA but incorrectly handled it. 
Is this a known bug ? Are there any workaround available to this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [config.protectedSource](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-protectedSource) in config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.protectedSource.push( /<!\[CDATA\[[\s\S]*?\]\]>/g );
};
```

Once you start using protected source, you might find this plugin useful: http://ckeditor.com/addon/showprotected